# IE7 <li> bullet or number shown outside of div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists

I'm having issues with the IE7 list element bugs.  The bullets (or numerals) of  and  are being shown outside of the margin.  How do I fix this for IE?  From what I've read this seems to be a problem when specifying the height/width in an IE7 li.  Images can be found here:

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

IE7:

[image: IE7]

I have a stylesheet with the Meyer reset.

```
#create_request li {
    display: list-item;
    width: 313px;
    height: 23px;
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    list-style: decimal;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#create_request li.alternate {
    background-color: white;

}

#create_left li:hover {
    width: 356px;
    background: url('/images/list_add.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reset style sheet? If you do not that may be the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *From what I've read this seems to be a problem when specifying the height/width in an IE7 li.*

That's correct. Set the `width` on `<ol>` instead of the `<li>` and use `line-height` instead of `height` on the `<li>`.

```
#create_request ol {
    width: 313px;
}

#create_request li {
    line-height: 23px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Fix everything, but let to this new bug:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078290/ie7-li-bullet-number-outside-of-hover

Answer (score 1):

IE can do some weird things with padding/margin. I would recommend having a separate .css file for IE:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

And then just add either padding-left or margin-left to bump it back in place.

Answer (score 0):

1) try `display: block;` instead of `display: list-item;`

2) try using margin (even margin-left:0;)

3) CSS hack for IE7 is also available

```
*+html #create_request li{

     ..... some style corrections here will work for IE7  .....

}
```