# IE7 <li> bullet/number outside of hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Follow-up from another post here: [IE7 li bullet or number shown outside of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076730/ie7-li-bullet-or-number-shown-outside-of-div)

In the previous post, the li element outside the div was fixed, but now I have another IE7 bug with the hover element.  Since the hover element can not be set through the , how do I fix this one?

P.S. Obviously I've been having some trouble with the hasLayout bug in IE, so it someone was to give a nice explanation it would be appreciated.

Again everything works in firefox, etc.

The screenshots:
[image: Firefox]
[image: IE7]

The code:

```
#create_request ol {
    width: 339px;

}

#create_request li {
    display: list-item;
    line-height: 23px;
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    list-style: decimal;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#create_request li.alternate {
    background-color: white;

}

#create_left li:hover {
    width: 356px;
    background: url('/images/list_add.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible without bringing in another element in the `<li>`. The incorrect `list-style-position` behaviour occurs in IE6/7 when the `<li>` element get *hasLayout*. You want to totally avoid *hasLayout* on the element. The `width` is one of the *hasLayout* triggers.

I suggest to put a `<span>` in the `<li>` (yes, sorry if you would cry)

```
<li><span>Item</span></li>
```

and change the `li:hover` style as follows

```
#create_left li:hover {
    background: #B0B0B0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#create_left li:hover span {
    display: block;
    width: 356px;
    background: #B0B0B0 url('/images/list_add.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

This way the span controls the width of the `<li>` without giving it *hasLayout*. You only need to remove `padding-top: 5px;` from the `<li>`'s CSS and counteract it with `line-height`, otherwise the `<span>` will not get the full height.

Make it if necessary an IE6/7 conditional stylesheet.

Comment: I see where you are going, but as soon as I add the block style, the span gets thrown to the next line.  I would think display:inline-block would works, but that does not do the trick.  Here is what it looks like http://imgur.com/j4ycD

Comment: That's why I suggested to make it a conditional stylesheet.

Comment: Ahh, misunderstood what you said.  So implementing the above changes will break things in Firefox, but not in IE.  Everything worked with a conditional tag.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to declare "list-style-position" in the rule for your OL tag:

```
#create_request ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```